# Syntax for VTK HEXAHEDRON class

Tags: mesh, vtk, paraview

I am trying to display the scalar field associated with 20 unconnected cubes on Paraview. For this, I am trying to use the HEXAHEDRON vtk class. The file I created reads as follows:

```
Test
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 160 FLOAT
19.098110 12.993696 27.966301
23.098110 12.993696 27.966301
23.098110 16.993696 27.966301
...
HEXAHEDRA 120 600
4 0 1 5 4
4 1 2 6 5
4 2 3 7 6
4 3 0 4 7
4 0 1 2 3
4 4 5 6 7
4 8 9 13 12
4 9 10 14 13
4 10 11 15 14
4 11 8 12 15
4 8 9 10 11
4 12 13 14 15
...
```

However, Paraview gives an `"Unrecognized keyword: 3"` error. I have tried changing the keyword to `POLYGONS` and Paraview was happy (although I wasn't, as all the cubes got joined up).

What is the right keyword for the `VTK_HEXAHEDRON` class? I have tried `HEXAHEDRA`, `HEXAHEDRON` and `HEXAHEDRONS` with no success...

Thank you,
Marta

Answer (score 3):

You should use the keyword `VTK_HEXAHEDRON`.
For more information, see the section **19.3 VTK File Formats** in [VTK User’s Guide](https://vtk.org/vtk-users-guide/).

Answer (score -1):

You could use Python to create the mesh and then [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) (one of my projects) to write it any format you like, e.g., VTK.

```py
import meshio
import numpy

hex_mesh = meshio.Mesh(
    numpy.array(
        [
            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
            [1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
            [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
            [0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
        ]
    ),
    {"hexahedron": numpy.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]])},
)

meshio.write("out.vtk", hex_mesh)
```

```
# vtk DataFile Version 4.2
written by meshio v3.3.1
ASCII
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTS 8 double
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
CELLS 1 9
8
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
CELL_TYPES 1
12
```